# Scraping data from url in php, first url is working but not others which have same structure only id is different

Tags: php, arrays, json, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I scrape data from the following urls:

```
-e.g:http://www.example.com/?api=de&id=100
-e.g:http://www.example.com/?api=de&id=101
-e.g:http://www.example.com/?api=de&id=102
-e.g:http://www.example.com/?api=de&id=103
```

1. I can access all url directly and see all the data is there in Json
   format.
2. I tried without simple_html_dom.
3. I tried with
   simple_html_dom (With file_get_contents,file_get_html).

By using above method i can only see the data of `"id=100"` but when I change the id to 101 or 102 etc. it does not work. All the urls have the same structure, only the `id` is different.

I tried `simple_html_dom` (With `file_get_contents`, `file_get_html`) Also without `simple_html_dom, however in both cases I get the same result as empty except for the first url.

```
   //First Method
   $url = "http://www.example.com/?api=de&id=101";
   $json = file_get_contents($url);
   $MyData = json_decode($json, true);
   print_r($MyData); // Giving Empty Array (i.e.array())

   //Second Method
   $fileget = new simple_html_dom();
   $url = "http://www.example.com/?api=de&id=101";
   $json = file_get_html($url);
   print_r($MyData); // Giving Empty Array (i.e.array())
```

But when I set `id=100` then all is working well. (**Here the output is Correct**)

```
   // Now with id=100
   $url = "http://www.example.com/?api=de&id=100";
   $json = file_get_contents($url);
   $MyData = json_decode($json, true);
   print_r($MyData); 
   //Output is
   [{"name":"A","class":"1"},{"name":"B","class":"2"},{"name":"C","class":"3"}]
```

I don't get why, when the urls all have the same structure, only first one works and not the others.

Comment: Explain why you thought simplehtmldom would work on one page, when the other was json. Do you understand the difference between the two?

Comment: actually just i tried with simplehtmldom becz the things are not working there

Comment: What is the output of `print($json)`?

Comment: blank like [ ] this

Comment: Is this an actual API you are supposed to use this way - or are you trying to scrape data from a page that perhaps doesn’t really want you to, and therefor might be taking measures against it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a try catch block and print the exception variable. Also try printing $json value . You may be able track the issue cause

Comment: Try reading url using Curl $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$yourUrl);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

Comment: curl_setopt giving output as 1 and $result output is [].

Comment: Nobody is there who knows these things?